# List is empty in adapter recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, searchview

I want to do search in list of recycler view with room db. In mhetod setAll i set in arraylist of lists the some values this values sets once (i debug)

```
    internal fun setAll(productEntity: List<ProductEntity>) {
        this.filterListResult = productEntity
        lists.addAll(filterListResult)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
```

after on search this lists has become is empty

```
 override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return object : Filter() {
            override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {

                val charSearch = constraint.toString()
                if (charSearch.isEmpty())
                    filterListResult = productsList
                else {
                    val resultList= ArrayList<ProductEntity>()

                    lists.size
                    for (row in lists){
                        if(row.productName.toLowerCase().contains(charSearch.toLowerCase()))
                            resultList.add(row)
                    }

                    filterListResult = resultList
```

Comment: Could you please post your adapter's code as well?

Comment: Why not use `.filter { }` predicate on your list? It's much more readable than overriding `getFilter()`

Comment: on my git yo can whatch my adapter on last commit searchview dont work https://github.com/frolix/TestApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/testappfinal/adapter/ProductListAdapter.kt